# ava.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the ApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring, javabeans, illegalstateexception

I am getting this error from this line of code - 'ContextHolder.getContext().getBean(org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource.class)' **sometimes** **(not all the time)**.

Most of the time when it gets this error, the program retries after few minutes and recovers.

The snippet of the code from where it is coming :

```
import javax.sql.DataSource;
......

public class DAOUtil
{

    public final static Connection getOracleConnection(  ) throws DAOException
    {
        DataSource dataSource = ContextHolder.getContext().getBean(org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource.class);
        try
        {
            return dataSource.getConnection();
        }
        catch ( SQLException e )
        {
            throw new DAOException( "failed to get connection from data source",e );
        }
    }

  ......
}fr
```

In the Spring context this org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource bean is described as :

```
<bean id="projDataSource" class="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource"
      destroy-method="close" lazy-init="true">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
    <property name="url" ref="projDsUrl"/>
    <property name="username"
              value="#{props[T(daffel.digital.web.Constants).PROPS_DB_USERNAME]}"/>
    <property name="password" ref="decryptedPwd"/>
    <property name="initialSize" value="5"/>
    <property name="maxActive" value="10"/>
    <property name="maxIdle" value="5"/>
    <property name="minIdle" value="2"/>
    <property name="maxWait" value="10000"/>
    <property name="validationInterval" value="10000"/>
    <property name="validationQuery" value="select 1 from dual"/>
    <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

This getOracleConnection(  ) method is being called in try-with-resource way:

```
try (Connection connection = DAOUtil.getOracleConnection();
         PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement
                    ( GET_QUERY );
         ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()) {
        while (rs.next()) {
            //do something
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        String msg = "Query failed: " + GET_QUERY;
        LOG.error(msg, e);
        throw new DAOException(msg, e);
    }
```

Any insight?

Comment: Why this contraption? Wy not simply inject the `DataSource` instead of using the `getOracleConnection` method? Or even better use a `JdbcTemplate` to reduce the clutter/boilerplate code.

Comment: Oracle connection is used in different parts of the project.We need to keep that method

Comment: The fact that it is. used in a different part doesn't mean you have to forget about dependency injection? The problem is there is no guarantee that everything has been setup already with this contraption.